# Extracting 'year' from a column

Tags: python, regex-group, try-except

I have a working code, but I think my logic isn't on the right path (although it works). I just need some help with optimizing it. Essentially, to see if what I did was an acceptable way of doing what I am doing or if there's a better way. I am rooting for the latter, because I know what I did isn't the "right" way.

I have a `pd` column of strings with "year" in it and I am trying to extract it from it. The problem is that a few entries do not have a year listed. So something like this:

| Index | string_values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | String A (1995) |
| 1 | String B (1995) |
| 2 | String C (1995) |
| 3 | String D has no year |
| 4 | String E has (something in braces) AND also the year (2003) |

`re.search('\d{4}', df['string_values '][0]).group(0)` works, but in a for loop, it throws this error (I guess when it hit the non-4-digit string): `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. I think this because `len(_temp)` gives `15036` and it has the *years* listed. Just that it's throwing this error.

Here's the `for` loop:

```
_temp = []
for i in df['string_values']:
    year = re.search("\d{4}", i)
    if year.group():
        _temp.append(year.group())
    else:
        _temp.append(None)
```

Then I also tried the Try-Except way to do it, and that works - `len(<var>)` gives `62423`, which is also the total row in the df. And here's the code:

```
_without_year = []
_with_year = []
for i in df['string_values']:
    year = re.search("\d{4}", i)
    try:
        if year.group():
            # _with_year.append(year.group())
            pass
    except:
        _without_year.append(i)
```

I just need to know if what I did is acceptable. It works, like I said. `_without_year` does display all the entries without the year.

The thing with the Try-Except block is that I am `pass`ing on the `if` condition catching the `i`th error.

Comment: I think a better approach is to create a function, something like year_search(row). Use the apply function to grab your information. E.g. df['Year'] = df['String_values'].apply(year_search). This is much cleaner than a loop.

Comment: @Robert - Yes, but I'd like to find out the strings that do not have `year` in it. I suppose a loop is the only way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the year values directly:

```py
df['string_values'].str.extract(r'(?<=\()(\d{4})(?=\))', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
0    1995
1    1995
2    1995
3     NaN
4    2003
Name: string_values, dtype: object
```

Note I've used forward and backward lookarounds to assert that the year occurs inside parentheses; if you don't want that but just to match a 4-digit string replace them with `\b` (word break) e.g.

```py
df['string_values'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{4})\b', expand=False)
```

To convert the output to a list, you can use [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```py
df['string_values'].str.extract('(?<=\()(\d{4})(?=\))', expand=False).tolist()
```

Output:

```
['1995', '1995', '1995', nan, '2003']
```

To find the string values that don't contain a year, you can use [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to find matches and invert that to use as an index:

```py
df[~df['string_values'].str.contains(r'(?<=\()\d{4}(?=\))')]
```

Output:

```
   Index          string_values
3       3  String D has no year
```

Comment: Ok yes. This is nice, but I'd like to find out the strings that do not have the year in it. Not that `they do not have a year in it so NaN`. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson perhaps `df[~df['string_values'].str.contains('(?<=\()\d{4}(?=\))')]`?

Comment: If you can edit your answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: Accepted. Thank you, kind stranger named Nick.